# How was the expression 'rompere le scatole' born?

Tags: idioms, etymology

As a foreigner I have always found the expression 'rompere le scatole' to be very funny. I know its meaning and I was wondering where it comes from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As egreg has noted, *scatole* is currently used as an euphemism. There are other expression that use *scatole* as a replacement for *testicles*, like 'averne piene le scatole' or 'andare fuori dalle scatole'. [Here](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/S/scatola.shtml), [here](http://dizionarioitaliano.it/scatola/), and [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scatola_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) you can find references. However, I am not sure about the origin of the expression. Maybe it was not strictly linked to the meaning 'testicles'.

The expression was already used in the XIX century. The following quote is from Primiero, Antonio Prospero, Philippe Joseph Simon, and Badon Edmond, *I figli della calunniata. Dramma in 5 atti*, 1844.

> Ast. Andiamo, già fra vicine ed amiche...
>
> Raim. Fra vicine ed amiche già... ci possiamo rompere le scatole tutto il santo giorno, non è vero?

Comment: Amazing detective job :) Well done!

Answer (score 3):

The only info I could find on the net ([here](http://freeforumzone.leonardo.it/lofi/modi-di-dire-riciclati-/D9639335.html) and [here](http://www.netwargamingitalia.net/forum/threads/il-gergo-dei-soldati-italiani-nella-grande-guerra.14326/)) seem to point to the fact that during WWII, "to break the boxes" would refer to take ammo from their carton boxes, that is, an attack was imminent. It would be very cool if it was true, but both links lack any real source, so "caveat lector" ;)

Comment: Maybe this is true, but I think that the phrase is mainly an attenuation of the more vulgar *rompere le palle*.

Comment: Yes, the less intriguing, but pretty logical explanation is what most italians would consider the origin of this saying :) Anyways, those two links are the only ones I found that discuss where "rompere le scatole" came from. My parents were too young during WWII, but I'll try asking.

Comment: But one also says *scassare* which is again a reference to boxes (casse). This would mean that maybe is the other way around: *rompere le palle* o *scassare le palle* is derived from *rompere le scatole*.

Answer (score 0):

I remember my grandpa told me it has something to do with the tin pan that was used to cook the eggs for breakfast, which was also called "scatola". They would crack the egg smashing it slightly to the edge of the pan. So it would be a "scatola" that breaks the eggs, or "rompe le palle". Does it make sense?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! The meaning of "scatola" as a pan to cook the eggs seems somewhat strange to me. *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([here](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00897.jpg) and [here](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00898.jpg)), which is a quite complete Italian dictionary, doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Charo sei sicura che scattola con due T non fosse proprio l'intenzione dell'autore? cfr https://books.google.it/books?id=4YBPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA380&lpg=PA380&dq=dizionario+scattola&source=bl&ots=HUtUxEj9rR&sig=ACfU3U2byTIfxGBj51tPMwOlfdQCWxc1Bw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHzdi0hO_nAhUKbKwKHfvlBMgQ6AEwBXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=dizionario%20scattola&f=false

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: No, I'm not sure about that. But an orthographic error that is quite frequent among strangers seems more plausible to me that the intentionality of using an archaic form of this word.

Comment: @charo ok, but consider that was their (the poster) grand father speaking.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica, see: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scattola%2Cscatola&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscattola%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscatola%3B%2Cc0